# image rounded corner

Tags: html, css

I have a div containing an image. I want this div with rounded corners.
The problem is the image inside the div is bigger than the div and i use `overflow:hidden` to cut the image because with jquery i reduce the size on mouseover, so now the div has rounded corners but i can see them only when i reduce the size of the image.

```
    .thumb{
       float: left;
       overflow: hidden;
       width: 230px;
       height: 230px;
       position: relative;
       margin-right: 1px;
       margin-bottom: 1px;
       border-radius: 12px;
    }
    .thumb img {
       max-width: 270px;
       height: 270px;
       left: -20px;
       position: relative;
       top: -20px;
       width: 270px;
       border-radius: 12px;
   }
```

Comment: Please create a demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to elaborate the issue.

Comment: Questions normally have a question mark.

Comment: do you want an image inside a div with rounded corners? is that what you're asking?

Comment: have you added a width to the border?

Comment: I think you're looking is an inner-border solution: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839613/how-to-make-round-corners-to-both-inside-of-a-box-and-its-border

Comment: Yes, i want an image inside a div with rounded corners, but the image is bigger than the rect area of the div so right now i cannot see any borders because the image is cutted of by the overflow:hidden of the div.