# Mobile form help facebook style

Tags: html, css, facebook

Hello I am trying to make this form and its not looking right could anyone help fix it? Thank You for all the help :). http://jsfiddle.net/Srw6Q/

```
<form>
    <input style="font-size:46px; margin-bottom:-3px; border-bottom: solid 1px black; padding: 25px" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"> <br/>
    <input style="font-size:46px; border-bottom: solid 1px black; padding: 25px" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
</form>
```

[image: img]

Comment: what do you think is not right about this form ?

Comment: The curved sides and they don't look connected

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839613/how-to-make-round-corners-to-both-inside-of-a-box-and-its-border

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use padding for form and for curved used border-radius

Try

```
<form style="background: #425EA1; padding: 10px 20px">
    <input style="font-size:46px; margin-bottom:-3px; border-bottom: solid 1px black; padding: 25px; border-radius: 25px 25px 0 0" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"> <br/>
        <input style="font-size:46px; border-bottom: solid 1px black; padding: 25px; border-radius: 0 0 25px 25px;" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password"/>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tamilcselvan/5qHRD/