# rounded corners border around website

Tags: css, border, rounded-corners

I have border around whole website and it works great,now how can I make it have rounded corners,I've tried :

```
border-radius: 25px
```

but it doesnt work,and heres the normal border code that works but I need it rounded :

```
.ct, .cb, .cr, .cl {
border-radius: 25px
background-color: #ffffff;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999;
}
.ct {
border-radius: 25px
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
}
.cr {
border-radius: 25px
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 20px;
}
.cb {
border-radius: 25px
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
}
.cl {
border-radius: 25px
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 20px;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any border definitions. Without that, it won't do anything.

Comment: Also there's no ; after border-radius: 25px

Comment: I suppose his borders are these 4 classes

Comment: I added : border-radius: 25px; to each of these,but doesnt work for some reason. no clue why

Comment: yes borders are those 4 classes

Comment: Can't you use html { border: 20px solid color; } for your border instead of this?

Comment: all border-radius: 25px are missing ;

Comment: Hi guys,heres what happens when I add radius on it : http://imgur.com/a/KM3KB   I want that inner part rounded and outside to stay filled

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using div's as borders just use border: size type color;

https://jsfiddle.net/dcLbza26/

```css
html {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 20px solid red;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

Comment: awesome I will try it out now

Comment: Tried it works,but how can inner part also be rounded? Inner corners,heres the image that shows how it looks now : http://imgur.com/a/KM3KB

Comment: You can find some good answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839613/how-to-make-round-corners-to-both-inside-of-a-box-and-its-border

Comment: This code I tried and it works :  http://jsfiddle.net/DXLr9/    now how can i fill this part that shown on this screenshot : http://imgur.com/PHdr8Qa              2. Issue I have is all inside border is not clickable anymore,all pics inside it,dont know why