# How do I achieve a thick border with inner border radius only

Tags: css

```
border: 15px solid $card-border;
```

I want the outer border radius to be none, and the inner border radius to have a value (be rounded on the inside only).
How do I achieve that?

Comment: is this what you want https://stackoverflow.com/a/59383914/8620333 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
the simple way: you can have 2 dives 

<div class="a">
   <div class="b">
   </div>
</div>

.b{
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
 .a{
    border: 15px solid;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing as well! Thanks :)
Was looking for a solution with border properties, but there doesn't seem to be one.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood :

```
border: 1px double #000;
border-radius: 20px;
outline: none;
outline-offset: 0px;
```

Here **border** represent the inner border and **border-radius** decides the roundness of the border. Eventhough I haven't understood why you want to mention a outer border that's none, you could still do it by mentioning **outline** to none.

In case you want to put both the border and adjust the spacing you can use **outline-offset** to adjust the required spacing.

Hope that helpss.. !!

Comment: This is not what I am looking for.
I want a border of 15px (`border: 15px solid $card-border;`) which has sharp (perpendicular) outer edges but rounded inner edges. Your answers causes both the outer edge and the inner edge to become round.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving your element `box-sizing: border-box`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Answer (score -2):

For the outter element do nothing because **the default behavior of border-radius property is 0** and for the inner one

```
Your element selector { 
            border-radius: the value you want px
}
```