# How to create a container with rounded corners inside?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create something like this in Html + CSS.

[image: Box/Container with rounded corners inside]

I think it's possible to make it in at least 2 ways:

1) Create the box with 4 rectangles and 4 rounded corners (it's more code, but it will be easy to fix position if I want to scroll background content).

2) Just create a background with that color and create a container in the center with scroll javascript in that div.

WWYD or is there another easier way?

P.S. On top of page, logo (left), buttons/pictograms (center) and profile (right) - I might add another container for it.

Comment: Take e look at [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius).

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59383914/8620333

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use 2 divs with a border and radius for the inner one.  See here:

```css
#inside {
  border: 5px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  height: 200px;
  background: grey;
}

#outside {
  border: 5px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="outside">
  <div id="inside">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx. I can do something with this, but you already helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to use 2 DOM use [pseudo element `:before`](https://dev.to/finallynero/understanding-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-ml0)

```css
body{
padding: 15px;
}
div{
height:120px;
width:150px;
background-color:black;
border-radius:20px;
position:relative;
}

div:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 126%;
    width: 120%;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: -13%;
    left: -10%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: Didn't went as I wanted, the other answer helped me more and I used height: 100vh. Just need better padding, margin, etc.