# Round the inner corners inside the box-shadow?

Tags: html, css, border

How can I round the inner corners inside the `box-shadow`?

If I increase `border-radius` to `80px` then I see some whitespace between the `box-shadow` and the corners.

```css
div#secondSample {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

div#secondSample div#grid div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px 10px #0000FF, inset 3px 3px 20px 10px #0000FF80;
}

div#secondSample div#grid div:after {
  content: "need round these four corners here";
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 80px;
  border: 50px solid;
  box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 20px 10px green;
  border-image-slice: 1;
    border-image-source: linear-gradient(to left, darkgreen, lightgreen);
    color:#000;
    
}
```

```html
<div id="secondSample">
  <div id="grid">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. A `box-shadow` by definition is a shadow on the actual box and so has corners. Perhaps a `drop-shadow` instead?

Comment: What if I create a round `div` then will the shadow apply with corners?

Comment: Try it...I don't think it works but I could be wrong.

Comment: If the only way to achieve rounded corners is `border-radius` then I've tried it and it doesn't work

Comment: Then you'll have to rethink your methodology I'm afraid.

Comment: I tried increasing the border-radius, then I started seeing white space between the corners and box-shadow. Can you suggest any other way?

Comment: Unfortunately inner curves are problematical. Perhaps an overlay div with outer border radius?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not box-shadow but gradient on border combined with radius. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51496204/8620333) you can do it like below:

```css
div#grid div {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px 10px #0000FF, inset 3px 3px 20px 10px #0000FF80;
}

div#grid div:after {
  content: "need round these four corners here";
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 80px;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 20px 10px green;
}

div#grid div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 50px;
  border-radius: 80px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, darkgreen, lightgreen);
  -webkit-mask: 
    linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, 
    linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite: destination-out;
  mask-composite: exclude;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

And if you want only inner corner you can use a different mask based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59383914/8620333)

```css
div#grid div {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px 10px #0000FF, inset 3px 3px 20px 10px #0000FF80;
}

div#grid div:after{
  content: "need round these four corners here";
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 80px;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 20px 10px green;
}


div#grid div:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, darkgreen, lightgreen);
  --r: 30px 30px content-box; /* control the radius here */
  -webkit-mask: 
     radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right,transparent 98%,#fff 100%) top left    / var(--r),
     radial-gradient(farthest-side at top    right,transparent 98%,#fff 100%) bottom left / var(--r),
     radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom left ,transparent 98%,#fff 100%) top right   / var(--r),
     radial-gradient(farthest-side at top    left ,transparent 98%,#fff 100%) bottom right/ var(--r),
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) content-box, 
     linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  mask-composite: exclude;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
    <div></div>
  </div>
```

If you don't want transparency, simply like below:

```css
div#grid div {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 20px 10px #0000FF, inset 3px 3px 20px 10px #0000FF80;
}

div#grid div:after{
  content: "need round these four corners here";
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 80px;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  background:#fff padding-box;
  box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 20px 10px green;
}


div#grid div:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, darkgreen, lightgreen);
  
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
    <div></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Does this only support Chrome?

Comment: @TempO'rary no, it should work in all modern borwsers (Chrome Firefox and Edge) [I have tested the 3]

Comment: @TempO'rary added a third idea that should support old browser but you won't have transparency